# Run string as static class function in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm receiving prepared function as strings like these:

```
"\app\models\AddrModel::getText('A_00001724');"
```

Now I need to convert and run this string as static function call, to retrieve the value if the `A_00001724` id.

**How do I do that?**

PS: When I call it as `$value = new $function;` I get

```
Class '\app\models\AddrModel::getText('A_00001724')' not found
```

since it's not just class. It`s static function with class :/

Comment: What about $value = eval( 'return '."\app\models\AddrModel::getText('A_00001724');" ) ?

Comment: @Mat I checked the docs, `eval` doesn't return any value, so this wont work for me.

Comment: eval does return a value if the evalued code returns a value. My test case is : `$func = "sprintf('%s %s', 'hello', 'world');";
$value = eval('return '.$func);
print_r($value); // echo "hello world"`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also found the same solution: `$value = eval('return '.$function.';');`. You should put it as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: just notice that `eval` is a bit risky in some cases so make sure the `$function` value is being checked and validated prior to usage.

Comment: try to check this http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval() can be used to execute php code in a string. Eval() returns a value if the executed code returns a value.

So, in the case above :

```
$func = "\app\models\AddrModel::getText('A_00001724');";
$value = eval('return ' . $func);
print_r($value);
```

Comment: it is needless to say that eval is a very bad Idea, and perhaps you should change your approach in solving your problem